# Keep input in fragment when switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have 4 tabs holding a fragment. When I switch from fragment 2 to any other fragment I want to keep the fragments state (it has input fields for uploading an item to a server).

I have tried using **addToBackStack** but it would end up with all fragments having it to be able to keep my fragment 2's state.

This is what I want:

```
Fragment 1 = home
Fragment 2 = upload
Fragment 3 = edit
Fragment 4 = support

2 -> 1 = keep 2's state
2 -> 3 = keep 2's state
1 -> 2 = resume 2's state
3 -> 2 = resume 2's state
1 -> 3 = keep 2's state
3 -> 1 = keep 2's state
etc..
```

I have over 30 inputfields in upload and I dont want to store all information in SQLite for every time any EditText text changes.

If I use addToBackStack then I can go from home to support to edit and so on. I don't want that! Yelp!

Comment: Try reading about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and how to save and restore states.

Comment: `When I switch from fragment 2` define *switch* ... if you just hide/show the state should remain ... add/remove will recreate the Fragment ...

Comment: I use `transaction` with `replace` and `commit`. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26651072/3064486) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not suite for your needs, but if you can, instantiate a fragment only once:

```
private MyFragment mMyFragment;
private MyOtherFragment mMyOtherFragment;
```

Init them somewhere and reuse them without instantiate them again

Comment: This worked. In my activity I used Fragment f = new Fragment(); and then in my switch for the tabs I used f as target instead of new Fragment();

Comment: Exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score -1):

adding to backStack doesnt store the information. for that u have to use RetainInstanceState.

Override a method to setRetainInstance as shown:

```
@Override
public void setRetainInstance(boolean retain) {
    super.setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Then in onAttach method of fragment, put this:

```
getRetainInstance();
```

Comment: `Override a method to setRetainInstance` what for?